# How can I call an Azure function from the client application and add one or more function parameters?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I want to call this Azure function from the client application but I don't know how to do the http request.

Azure function:

```
    [FunctionName("ChangeDisplayname")]
    public static async Task<dynamic> MakeApiCall(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
    {
        var context = await FunctionContext<dynamic>.Create(req);
        var args = context.FunctionArgument;

        var desireddisplayname = args["NewDisplayname"];

        var request = new UpdateUserTitleDisplayNameRequest();
        request.PlayFabId = context.CallerEntityProfile.Lineage.MasterPlayerAccountId;
        request.DisplayName = desireddisplayname;
       
        var adminApi = new PlayFabAdminInstanceAPI(context.ApiSettings, context.AuthenticationContext);

        return await adminApi.UpdateUserTitleDisplayNameAsync(request);
    }
```

This is my client application code to call the Azure function. But it is not working because I don't know how to add **desireddisplayname** to the http request. **desireddisplayname** should be the function parameter "NewDisplayname". For example, if desireddisplayname = "Chris", then var desireddisplayname should have the same value "Chris" when I call the Azure function.

Is it somehow possible to add **desireddisplayname** when I use await _httpClient.GetAsync(url)?

How can I call an Azure function from the client application and add one or more function parameters?

```
    public static async Task<(bool requestexecuted, string desireddisplayname, string errormessage)> Azurehttprequest(this string url)
    {
        bool requestexecuted = false;
        string errormessage = string.Empty;

        var _httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15) };

        try
        {
            using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    requestexecuted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    requestexecuted = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            requestexecuted = false;
        }

        return (requestexecuted, errormessage);
    }
```

Comment: Did you go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient)? Azure function http trigger acts like a REST api endpoint. So you would call it like normally. In this case your function is allowing post, so you would use [`PostAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync) in the client.

Comment: I don't understand how to call my Azure function from the client with PostAsync. Could you explain me how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to call your endpoint from Postman? First do a test via postman, then try to call from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your function is an [HttpTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp) and is HTTP POST endpoint as per `[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]` - you will have to call this function's Endpoint with `HTTP POST` method and not `HTTP GET`.

Below is the code you might want to use instead:

**Client:**

```
using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri))
            {
                var body = new RequestModel
                {
                    NewDisplayname = desireddisplayname
                };

                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (responseMsg == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                            string.Format(
                                "The response message was null when executing operation {0}.",
                                request.Method));
                    }

                    return responseMsg;
                }
```

**Function code to read:**

```
// Get request body
                RequestModel data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<RequestModel>();
                name = data.NewDisplayname;
```

Comment: What is RequestModel data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<RequestModel>(); What is "req"? Where should I use this code? In addition, I get an error message: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RequestModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) How can I fix this problem?

Comment: req is HttpRequestMessage as in your question. You will have to create separate class RequestModel with a public property named NewDisplayName.