# I get error messages when I use RequestModel

Tags: c#

[How can I call an Azure function from the client application and add one or more function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027552/how-can-i-call-an-azure-function-from-the-client-application-and-add-one-or-more)

I get an error message when I try to use the code from the link.

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        {
            var body = new RequestModel
            {
                NewDisplayname = desireddisplayname
            };

            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (responseMsg == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    string.Format(
                        "The response message was null when executing operation {0}.",
                        request.Method));
            }
            else
            {
                if (responseMsg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // Get request body
                    RequestModel data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<RequestModel>();
                    string name = data.NewDisplayname;
                }
            }
        }
```

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RequestModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> Error CS0103: The name 'req' does not exist in the current context

How can I use 'RequestModel' in my code?

Comment: **First Error:** Do you have a `reference` to the `namespace` which contains `RequestModel`??? **Second Error:** is a typo on your part, change this: `RequestModel data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<RequestModel>();` to `RequestModel data = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<RequestModel>();`

Comment: Few tips: 1) [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples) is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. 2) `HttpResponseMessage` is `IDisposable` 3) `responseMsg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK` can be replaced with `responseMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode` or `throw` with `responseMsg.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` 4) `RequestModel data = JsonConvert.DeserealizeObject<RequestModel>(await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())`

Comment: Which using directive contains RequestModel?